# how to fetch subCategories based on categories angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, ajax

Below is my JSON data.

**JSON**

```
{
"1":{"id":"1","name":"Websites IT & Software","sub_cat":[
    {"id":"1","name":"Build a Website","description":"Build a Website"},
    {"id":"2","name":"Build an Online Store","description":"Build an Online Store"},
    {"id":"3","name":"Get Traffic to my Website ","description":"Get Traffic to my Website "},
    {"id":"4","name":"Write some Software","description":"Write some Software"},
    {"id":"5","name":"Convert a Template to a Website","description":"Convert a Template to a Website"},
    {"id":"53","name":"Create a Wordpress Template","description":"Create a Wordpress Template"},
    {"id":"54","name":"Create a Joomla Template","description":"Create a Joomla Template"},
    {"id":"55","name":"Create a Drupal Template","description":"Create a Drupal Template"},
    {"id":"56","name":"Develop a Mac Application","description":"Develop a Mac Application"}
    ]},
"2":{"id":"2","name":"Mobile","sub_cat":[
    {"id":"6","name":"Write an iPhone application","description":"Write an iPhone application"},
    {"id":"7","name":"Write an iPad application","description":"Write an iPad application"},
    {"id":"8","name":"Write a Blackberry application","description":"Write a Blackberry application"},
    {"id":"9","name":"Write an Android application","description":"Write an Android application"},
    {"id":"57","name":"Create a Mobile Website","description":"Create a Mobile Website"}]}}
```

All what I want is to fetch subcategories based on category that user choose and I wanted to implement same thing in angular way. Do I need to make an Ajax again to fetch subcategory based on category.

Any thoughts on how can I achieve this, help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you mean: how to access JSON keys to send over AJAX?

Comment: Go through tutorial on angular documentation site . Will show you several possible solutions. Question is far too broad

Comment: @DiegoGallegos No i want to fetch sub_cat depending on category user choose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to remove `"1"` and `"2"` keys from your object, and make just an array of objects as following:

```
$scope.categories = [{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Websites IT & Software",
      "sub_cat": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Build a Website",
        "description": "Build a Website"
      }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Build an Online Store",
        "description": "Build an Online Store"
      }]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Mobile",
      "sub_cat": [{
        "id": "6",
        "name": "Write an iPhone application",
        "description": "Write an iPhone application"
      }, {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "Write an iPad application",
        "description": "Write an iPad application"
      }]
    }];
```

Then you need to use [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) and [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directives to display all you need. As example:

```
<select ng-options="item as item.name for item in categories" ng-model="selectedCategory">
</select>

    <table class="table">
      <thead><tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Description</th>
      </tr></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="subCategory in selectedCategory.sub_cat">
          <td>{{subCategory.id}}</td>
          <td>{{subCategory.name}}</td>
          <td>{{subCategory.description}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

---

Plunkr available: http://plnkr.co/edit/me0vis?p=preview

Comment: I want to change the value to the name Category <option label="Mobile" value="object:5">Mobile</option>

Comment: use `track by item.name` in `ng-options`. Already answered your question, but leave it here too @ChadidiAbdellah

Answer (score -1):

You can try using a 3rd party library by the name underscore.js. It adds many usefull functions like "where":

`_.where(list, properties)` Looks through each value in the list, returning an array of all the values that contain all of the key-value pairs listed in properties.

```
_.where(listOfPlays, {author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611}); => [{title: "Cymbeline", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611}, {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611}]
```

Here is a link to the library's page http://underscorejs.org/#where

You can also use lodash: https://lodash.com/